# Dynamic filters and reactive plot in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, drop-down-menu, shiny

**Issues between inputs and plot output**

Hi,

I'm testing out a basic ShinyApp where I can generate a plot of commercial services broken down by geography and service type.

The idea is I want the user to use three drop-down menu inputs, each dependent upon the previous selection, to subset the data, which then gets output in a ggplot.

However, I'm having issues connecting the inputs to the plot output (see below). The inputs are working fine and reactive when selected, but I can't work out how to link that to the plot, I get the feeling I'm not using the right data source (but have no idea how to ensure it is). Furthermore, I'm not familiar with how I would go about adding a third filter (for "service") seeing as I don't know how to link my data source in the first place.

Sorry this is probably simple, but some help would be really appreciated.

**UI**

```
 #Data
 Test <- dataframe(
           Geography1 = c("Region","Local Authority","County"...),
           Geography2 = c("North West","Aldershot","Cheshire"...),
           Service = c("Shop","Cafe","Library"...),
           Overall_rating = c("Awesome","Good","Fantatstic"...),
           Locations = c(4000, 1300, 1700...)
  )

 #SHINY APP
 ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tool"),
   sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     uiOutput("geography1"),
     uiOutput("geography2"),
     uiOutput("service")),

  mainPanel(
     plotOutput("plot", height = "400px"))
     )
  )
```

**Server**

```
   server <- function(input, output) {

 output$geography1 = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "geog1",
              label = "Geography 1:", 
              choices = as.character(unique(Test$Geography1)),
              selected = "Region")
  })

 output$geography2 = renderUI({

   datasub <- Test[Test$Geography1 == input$geog1, "Name"]

     selectInput(inputId = "geog2", 
                 label = "Geography2:", 
                 choices = unique(datasub),
                 selected = unique(datasub)[1])
  })

  output$service = renderUI({

     datasub2 <- unique(datasub)

     selectInput(inputId = "service",
                 label = "Service type:",
                 choices = unique(...),
                 selected = unique(...)[1])
   })

  output$plot = renderPlot({

    ggplot(datasub2(),aes(x = Overall_rating, y = Locations, fill= Overall_rating))+
     geom_bar(stat = "identity")

   })
 }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: well one error is that you should change your `renderPlot()` to  `datasub <- Test[Test$Geography1 == input$geog1, "Name"]`;
    `ggplot(datasub,x = Overall_rating, y = Locations, fill= Overall_rating)+
     geom_bar(stat = "identity")`,....you did not create a reactive variable datasub2, but you are referencing one,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell how the provided data is supposed to be filtered in the app but this code will at least run and be interactive. Hopefully from there you can figure out how to adjust the dataset.

As BigDataScientist said one fault is that you're not using a reactive dataset.

```
#Data
Test <- data.frame(
  Geography1 = c("Region","Local Authority","County"),
  Geography2 = c("North West","Aldershot","Cheshire"),
  Service = c("Shop","Cafe","Library"),
  Overall_rating = c("Awesome","Good","Fantatstic"),
  Locations = c(4000, 1300, 1700)
)

#SHINY APP
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Tool"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("geography1"),
      uiOutput("geography2"),
      uiOutput("service")),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot", height = "400px"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$geography1 = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "geog1",
                label = "Geography 1:", 
                choices = as.character(unique(Test$Geography1)),
                selected = "Region")
  })

  datasub <- reactive({
    Test[Test$Geography1 == input$geog1,]
  })

  output$geography2 = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "geog2", 
                label = "Geography2:", 
                choices = unique(datasub()[,"Geography2"]),
                selected = unique(datasub()[,"Geography2"])[1])
  })

  datasub2 <- reactive({
    datasub()[Test$Geography2 == input$geog2, ]
  })

  output$service = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "service",
                label = "Service type:",
                choices = unique(datasub2()[,"Service"]),
                selected = unique(datasub2()[,"Service"])[1])
  })

  datasub3 <- reactive({
    datasub()[Test$Service == input$service, ]
  })

  output$plot = renderPlot({
    ggplot(datasub3(),aes(x = Overall_rating, y = Locations, fill= Overall_rating))+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")

  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Juergen. Thanks for your help on this.

Bit of a follow-up: 

The plot is to show the number of locations (y axis) by rating (a categorical vairable along X axis). So I want to give the user the ability to filter these data across different geographical hierarchies, e.g. number of rated locations in the North West (Region) or number of rated locations in East Sussex (Local Authority).

Having run the code you suggested (thank you), it's a great start, but I'm having issues with "Length of logical index must be 1 or 49311, not 197244". Data is not filtering through fully.

Comment: Can you please provide a dataset for the reproducible example? Otherwise it's difficult to guess where it's going wrong. I think the dataset in the example doesn't make any sense for filtering.